# SQLSTATE[08S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SMux Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF]

Tags: sql-server, excel, laravel

I need to import big excel files and insert them into the Mssql database using the Laravel console command.

`PHP version 8.1.1`

`pdo_sqlsrv version 5.10.1+15814`

`sqlsrv version 5.10.1+15814`

`Laravel version 9`

I use the `Box/spout` package for reading big excel files.

I create the console command and run this format

`php artisan excel:movement-data --index={this option contain number of sheets of excel}`

```
public function handle(): int
{
    if (Schema::hasTable('INTEGRATION_DOC_MOVEMENT_DATA_TABLE') === false) {
        Schema::create('INTEGRATION_DOC_MOVEMENT_DATA_TABLE', static function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('DOC_MOV_ID')->default(0)->nullable();
            $table->integer('DOC_ID')->default(0)->nullable();
            $table->integer('FROM_USER_ID')->default(0)->nullable();
            $table->integer('TO_USER_ID')->default(0)->nullable();
            $table->string('FROM_DEP_ID')->nullable();
            $table->string('TO_DEP_ID')->nullable();
            $table->string('DATE_SENT')->nullable();
            $table->string('DATE_RECIEVED')->nullable();
            $table->integer('STATUS_ID')->nullable();
            $table->integer('IS_ACTIVE')->nullable();
            $table->integer('SIDENOTE_ID')->nullable();
            $table->integer('MOV_LEVEL')->nullable();
            $table->text('NOTE')->nullable();
            $table->integer('IS_ORGINAL')->nullable();
            $table->integer('RETURNER_EMP_ID')->default(0);
            $table->string('DATE_SENT_SYSDATE');
            $table->string('LAST_UPDATED_DATE');
        });
        $this->info('[x] Table Created');
    }
    ini_set('memory_limit', '10000000000');
    $path = '/files/DOC_MOVEMENT_DATA_TABLE.xlsx';
    $filePath = public_path($path);
    $reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createXLSXReader($path);
    try {
        $reader->open($filePath);
        $this->info('[x] File opened');
    } catch (IOException|Exception $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }

    try {
        $data = [];
        $fieldNames = ['DOC_MOV_ID',
            'DOC_ID',
            'FROM_USER_ID',
            'TO_USER_ID',
            'FROM_DEP_ID',
            'TO_DEP_ID',
            'DATE_SENT',
            'DATE_RECIEVED',
            'STATUS_ID',
            'IS_ACTIVE',
            'SIDENOTE_ID',
            'MOV_LEVEL',
            'NOTE',
            'IS_ORGINAL',
            'RETURNER_EMP_ID',
            'DATE_SENT_SYSDATE',
            'LAST_UPDATED_DATE'
        ];
        $sheetIndex = $this->option('index');
        $this->info('[x] File starting for read');
        foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheetKey => $sheet) {
            if ($sheetKey === (int)$sheetIndex) {
                foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $key => $row) {
                    if (((int)$sheetIndex === 1 && $key > 1) || ((int)$sheetIndex > 1 && $key >= 1)) {
                        $cells = $row->getCells();
                        $rowData = [];
                        $multipleArrays = new MultipleIterator();
                        $multipleArrays->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($cells));
                        $multipleArrays->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($fieldNames));
                        foreach ($multipleArrays as $multipleArray) {
                            try {
                                $value = $this->checkObject($multipleArray[0]->getValue());
                                $rowData[$multipleArray[1]] = $value;
                            } catch (ReflectionException|Exception $e) {
                                dd($e->getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                        $data[] = $rowData;
                        unset($rowData, $cells);
                    }


                }
                try {
                    foreach ($this->chunk($data, 100) as $chunk) {
                        DB::transaction(function () use ($chunk, $sheetKey) {
                            if (DB::table('INTEGRATION_DOC_MOVEMENT_DATA_TABLE')->insert($chunk)) {
                                $this->output->info("[x] Record Successfully inserted to sheet number $sheetKey");
                            } else {
                                $this->output->warning("[x] Record doesn't inserted to sheet number $sheetKey");
                            }

                        }, 6);
                    }
                } catch (Throwable|Exception $e) {
                    dd($e->getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    } catch (ReaderNotOpenedException|ReflectionException|Throwable|Exception $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }
    $reader->close();
    $this->info('[x] File Closed');
    return CommandAlias::SUCCESS;
}
```

When I run this command, the application writes successfully the first sheet, but when I give option index 2, the application writes half of the data to the DB and then gives this error message

```
SQLSTATE[08S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SMux Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF]
```

Note: I'm working first time in MsSQl and I don't understand the reason for the error

Comment: Hi, i'm facing the same issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Jed you must using the Queue

Comment: I am using the Queue but somehow I still encounter the problem. My database is on a different server than my Queue server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use laravel Job and Queues, so as this task can be done in the background and later send email with an attachment of the output excel and the problem might be execution time.
Here is the link below
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#creating-jobs

Comment: This code must work once because these excel must be uploaded to a database. So I think don't need a job or queues. Please give me more detail if I think wrong(or maybe I don't understand what you say).

Comment: It is advisable to load in background if you are dealing with big files which takes time to execute. if you run it in a queue it will work. as you said that it records few data and stop.

Comment: actually yeah, this command records a few million data and stops. I'll try it. But I think my problem doesn't relate to the job and queue. Btw thank you for your answer

Comment: If you record millions of rows. It is better you use laravel queue